# code "ENTER" to buffer serial port in VC++

Tags: c++, serial-port

I need to put code enter to send by serial port, I use Visual C++ 2010.

```
sprintf_s(bufff,"X");    //code X
oSerial.WriteData(bufff,1); Sleep(500);

sprintf_s(bufff,"\n\r");    // code "enter"
oSerial.WriteData(bufff,1); Sleep(500);

sprintf_s(bufff,"A"); //code A   
oSerial.WriteData(bufff,1); Sleep(500);
```

I read the result by:

```
 oSerial.ReadData(buf,500);Sleep(500);
 printf("N: %s \n",buf);Sleep(10000);
```

And the result is:

```
 N:XA
```

So I think the "enter" code I put was wrong
could anyone has an answer?

Comment: \n\r is two bytes, yet you're only writing 1 byte.  Consider using a vector of char's, pushing data on it, and when writing using the vectors size.  And \r\n is the more typical ordering - not sure if that matters.

Comment: \n\r is _two_ characters, not one.

Comment: And the correct order is \r\n as in Ryan's comment!